# MySQL: Always select row with first of its kind

Tags: mysql

I have a table with multiple columns ordered by one attribute (Attr1) and I would like to select (with mySQL) always the first row of a new value:

[image]

How do I do this?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Sorry, for not stating my question clear enough.
Consider this new example table:
[image]

Let's say I run a blog with several posts which can can be commented by users. On the first page (the starting page) I want to list the newest comment for each post. I therefore get all comments and order them first by post_id, then by time stamp (ORDER BY post_id, time stamp DESC).
However, as I said, I'm only interested in the newest comment (for each post), not all of them. The desired output is therefore the orange rows as it is the newest comment for post_id 1, post_id 2 and post_id 3.

If I solved this with PHP I would simply take the whole table and loop through all rows and only echo the comment if the post_id doesn't match with the previous one.

Hope that makes it clearer. Is this possible with MySQL?

Comment: How are you identifying first row - do you have an id column, date or something else?

Comment: if you can order it by id and then the lowest should be the one you want to recieve, then I think it should work with a combination of GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Comment: @Julian can you please share your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want always the lowest ID as the first result AND you want all those lines which are orange, this would work for you!

```
SELECT * FROM your_table GROUPY BY Attr1 ORDER BY id
```

But as another answer said, he doesnt think that you want all those lines but instead only one then use his answer..

Database table:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: You should review the MySQL group by documentation particularly the bits which refer to indeterminacy and only_full_group_by.

Comment: im no expert and will read that, but if he wants all orange lines (which I thought) then this query works..

Answer (score 1):

Use `Limit` and `order by` clause

```
select * from your_table ORDER BY Attr1 desc Limit 1
```

Comment: this will only deliver one result, he wants multiple but only one with the same "name" "char" whatever.. in his example he wants to have 4 results (the orange one)

Comment: how you know he needs orange rows? i have not got anything from his question , he asked for 1 rows ("always the first row of a new value:"), so before giving downvote try to understand question not inner meaning of question  @ChristopherSupertramp

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp hope you give more down vote , it will help you a lot :)